# Haskell instance declaration affecting interpretation of class

Tags: haskell

The code below gives me this error unless the instance declaration is removed. Additionally, I have no idea what to Google, as the error isn't related to what seems to be causing the problem?

```
Test.hs|20 col 31 error| Could not deduce (Integral a) arising from a use of `gendivmod'
|| from the context (Euclidean a)
||   bound by the type signature for
||              gcdBezouts :: Euclidean a => a -> a -> (a, a, a)
||   at /home/jragonfyre/src/haskell/mathlib/Test.hs:17:15-50
|| Possible fix:
||   add (Integral a) to the context of
||     the type signature for
||       gcdBezouts :: Euclidean a => a -> a -> (a, a, a)
|| In the expression: gendivmod x y
|| In a pattern binding: (q, r) = gendivmod x y
|| In the expression:
||   let
||     (q, r) = gendivmod x y
||     (n, m, d) = gcdBezouts y r
||   in (m, n - m * q, d)
```

This is a MWE to reproduce the error on my machine.

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances, UndecidableInstances #-}

class (Num a, Eq a) => Euclidean a where
  genmod :: a -> a -> a
  genmod a = snd . gendivmod a
  gendiv :: a -> a -> a
  gendiv a = fst . gendivmod a
  gendivmod :: a -> a -> (a,a)
  gendivmod a b = (gendiv a b, genmod a b)
  isUnitEu :: a -> Bool
  isUnitEu = (==1) . abs

instance (Integral a) => Euclidean a where
  gendivmod = divMod

gcdBezouts :: (Euclidean a) => a -> a -> (a, a, a)
gcdBezouts 0 x = (0, 1, x)
gcdBezouts x 0 = (1, 0, x)
gcdBezouts x y = let (q, r) = gendivmod x y
                     (n, m, d) = gcdBezouts y r
                 in (m, n-m*q, d)
```

As for the motivation for not using a newtype, and going with the specific instance declaration, I have a lot of existing code that was written for integers that I wanted to generalize to work with polynomials as well, and I didn't want to have to rewrite it into an ugly mess with wrapping and unwrapping the newtype.

If there is another solution that will accomplish what I'd like, that would also be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure why you think you need a newtype.

The "superclass instance"

```
instance (Integral a) => Euclidean a where
```

which you probably think means "every instance of `Integral` is also an instance of `Euclidean`" actually means "*every type* is an instance of `Euclidean`, later adding the constraint that upon instantiation we require `Integral`".  Such instances are always going to cause you problems.

What I would recommend is explicitly instantiating `Euclidean` at each type you need it for (which also allows you to get rid of `UndecidableInstances`).

```
instance Euclidean Integer where
    ...
```

If you instantiate it at many `Integral` types, you should write helpers:

```
integralGenmod :: (Integral a) => a -> a -> a
...
```

Or, since your class has many methods, start by reifying:

```
data EuclideanDomain a = EuclideanDomain a {
    edGenmod :: a -> a -> a,
    ...
}
class Euclidean a where
    euclideanDomain :: EuclideanDomain a

genmod :: (Euclidean a) => a -> a -> a
genmod = edGenmod euclideanDomain    
...

integralEuclidean :: (Integral a) => EuclideanDomain a
integralEuclidean = EuclideanDomain { ... }

instance Euclidean Integral where
    euclideanDomain = integralEuclidean
```

which makes the explicit instantiation quite a bit more manageable, and will also allow you to state more of the compositional properties of your structure.  (Cf. this [post](https://lukepalmer.wordpress.com/2013/03/12/constructions-on-typeclasses-part-1-f-algebras/) where reifying a typeclass can get you a long way)

Comment: Ah I saw another post where something similar looked like it was solved with a newtype, but great thanks, that explains that.

Comment: Also it won't be so bad to instantiate at every integral type because `gendivmod` is the minimal complete definition, and for integral types this should just be equal to `divMod`.

Comment: If you need to write a lot of `Integral a => Euclidean a` instances, you can use DefaultSignatures and then you will only have to write `instance Euclidean Integer; instance Euclidean Int; ...`.